# What is the difference between a UWA and a UWP app

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, windows-store

What is the difference between a Universal Windows App (UWA) and a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app?

According to docs I have read, UWP is only for windows 10, but I know we hve Windows 8.1 universal apps.

Is there a good reference explaining the relationships between these technologies and how they appear in the Windows Store?

Comment: They are just meaningless marketing terms.  It is WinRT, current version is 1.4.  No major differences from 1.0, just incremental improvements.  WinRT has not been successful so coming up with another name for it makes it look like something new and different.  Microsoft always needed 3 major versions to get it right.

Answer (score 3):

- Windows 8.1 UWA (Universal Windows App), you can have two projects (Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1) that can share some code (shared project) or portable libraries.
- Windows 10 UWP (Universal Windows Platform), you can have a single project that can run on Windows 10, Windows 10 Mobile, Xbox One, Hololens, and Surface Hub.